# VBA code is removing formula from cells after copy and paste command

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which is working as I would expect in regards to it is copying my row of data and pasting into a new row.

It then clears the data from the original row ready for the next input.

The only problem is that it is removing all my formulas even though I have stated which cells are to be cleared in my code.

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Range("A9:Q9").Copy

Sheets("Raw data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

 Range("A9:Q9").Select
    Range("Q9").Activate
    
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A9").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B9").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("L9").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("M9").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("P9").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    Range("A9").Select
   
End Sub
```

Probably something ridiculously obvious.

Comment: First step: get rid of the `Select`ing, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: your first `Selection.ClearContents` is clearing `Range("A9:Q9")` as that is what is selected.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^ [`Range.Activate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.activate) is different than `Range.Select`, but you should be doing neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Range.Activate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.activate) is not the same as `Range.Select`, but you should be doing *neither* of those; change

```
Range("A9:Q9").Select
    Range("Q9").Activate
    
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A9").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B9").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("L9").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("M9").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("P9").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    Range("A9").Select
```

to

```
   Range("Q9").ClearContents
   Range("A9").ClearContents
   Range("B9").ClearContents
   ... and so on
```

See [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for a thorough discussion of how to improve your code.

Answer (score -1):

You are telling it to paste values... not formulas.

Try using xlPasteAll instead of xlPasteValues

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. When the paste is performed the data is being pasted into a new row in a separate worksheet (worksheet B) which I do not want the formulas in. However when I press my macro button after the paste has occurred (and this part works fine it is going onto the new row as required) I then want to clear certain cells from the main data entry worksheet (worksheet A), this is where it is going wrong as all cells are clearing instead of just the selecting which in turn is removing my formulas.